# Can this nonlinear vector equation be solved analytically?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, systems-of-equations

I have to solve the following vector equation:
$$
{\bf Ax} + {\bf b} + {\bf Cx}^{ \circ  - 1}  = {\bf 0}
$$
Where ${\bf b},{\bf x}, {\bf x}^{\circ  - 1}, {\bf 0} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$; ${\bf A},{\bf C} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $\bf C$ is a diagonal matrix. ${\bf x}^{\circ  - 1}$ is the Hadamard (pointwise) product inverse of ${\bf x}$, that means ${\bf x} \circ {\bf x}^{\circ  - 1} = {\bf 1} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. I thought about converting the equation into a quadratic vector equation and then "completing the square", but all my efforts were in vain. Is there any way of analytically solving this equation? whether by converting the equation into a quadratic one or any other method.

Comment: If $A = C = I$ and $b = 0$, the equation is not solvable.

Comment: Complex solutions are acceptable too.

Comment: Due to the text in your question, they are not.

Comment: I'm sorry, what I meant is that I don't mind if there exists an analytic solution that would yield complex values in such cases, as that would indicate me there are no real solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, you can express the numerator of each entry of the left side as a quadratic, and solve the system of quadratics using a Groebner basis.  I doubt that you'll get anything very nice in general: you'll likely end up "reducing" your system to a single polynomial of degree $2^n$ in one of the $x_i$ with unpleasant coefficients.